# SandCastle: Generating links for C# class name

Tags: c#, .net, documentation-generation, sandcastle

When I used doxygen for my C++ projects, I simply wrote:

```
/**
* I can refer to SomeClass or even SomeClass::someMethod() without special markup.
*/
```

Then doxygen generates links from "SomeClass" and "SomeClass::someMethod()" strings to appropriate documentation.

Now I work with C# and want to use SandCastle for generation documentation form C# code. I realized that links should be constructed with xml tag:

```
/// <see cref="SomeClass"/> and <see cref="SomeClass.someMethod()"/>
```

I think that it is very cumbersome and unreadable.

Is it any way to generate links for class and methods without special markup?
How do you generate documentation for C# projects?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it any way to generate links for class and methods without special
>   markup?

I don't think so. Actually the [XML documentation (format)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx) is not a feature of sandcastle, but of the C# compiler. Sandcastle (and other tools, like NDoc) "simply" build on it.

> How do you generate documentation for C# projects?

We're using [Sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/) and the [Sandcastle Helpfile Builder (SHFB)](http://shfb.codeplex.com/).
Also we're using [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) and ReSharper which help with writing and (on-the-fly) validating XML comments, for example if the type, method, or else you reference actually exist.

I think you could also use Doxygen and thus Doxygen style comments with your C# code, but personally I have never tried it. You'd have to check the Doxygen [website](http://www.doxygen.nl/). But you would miss out on features other tools provide based on the XML documentation (like [ReSharper's quick documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp50/Coding_Assistance__Quick_Documentation.html)) or most prominently, help-/description texts for Intellisense.